# Sort array a by value in array b in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

and another array:

```
b = [0, 3, 6, 3, 4, 0, 1]
```

Is it possible to sort array **a** according to values in array **b**?

The result should be:

```
a = ['c', 'e', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'a', 'f']
```

Something like this doesn't seem to exist in Ruby/Rails:

```
a.sort_with_index{ |elem, index| b[index] }
```

Edit: in response to the duplicate marking: the question being referred to has an array with elements having an ID, and the other array references the ID's directly. This is not the same, and the same solution will not apply...

Comment: Well, of course it's *possible*. It's a question of what's the cleanest, simplest way. `a.sort_by {|x| -b[a.index x] }` perhaps.

Comment: Another way: `a.values_at(*a.each_index.sort_by { |i| -b[i] }) #=> ["c", "e", "b", "d", "g", "a", "f"]`.

Comment: This is a pure-Ruby question so it should not have a Rails tag. That tag could be a small time-waster for readers only interested in Rails questions, but more importantly, readers who filter-out Rails questions might miss the opportunity to post a great answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just combine the two, sort, and strip out the original *a* values:

```
a.zip(b).sort_by { |_a, _b| -_b }.map { |_a,_| _a }
```

Comment: ...or `a.zip(b).sort_by(&:last).map(&:first).reverse #=> ["c", "e", "d", "b", "g", "f", "a"]`

Comment: It's close, but with duplicates the original order should precede.  That's why the result should be: ['c', 'e', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'a', 'f']

Comment: @rept That's a secondary sort consideration, but you didn't communicate that clearly in your question.

Answer (score 3):

```
a.sort_by.with_index { |_,i| [-b[i], i] }
  #=> ["c", "e", "b", "d", "g", "a", "f"]
```

This uses the indices of elements in `a` to break ties. I see from a comment on @tadman's answer that that is desired, though it is not a requirement given in the statement of the question. See the third paragraph of the doc for [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for an explanation of how arrays are ordered in sorting operations.